# Consuming latest messages from a topic and ignoring all previously published messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

Suppose I have a topic "test" which already have bunch of messages and now I want to subscribe to the topic. But I don't want to consume all the messages which are being published previous to the new subscription. Basically I want to consume only the latest messages which are published after my subscription.

Is there any feature in confluent.kafka library which can help me implement this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be the default behavior... Are you seeing something different?

Answer (score 1):

Use Group Consumer described in [here](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/consumer.html) and use `offset latest`. Then it will be consuming messages which produced after the group consumer subscription.